# Input doesn't work in Mobx Store at Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mobx

At first, I made 'Store' like below.
I want to put input in login state on realtime.

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'

export default class SingUpIn {
  @observable initialState = {
    register: {
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      passwordConfirm: ''
    },
    login: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  @action changeLogin = (name, value) => {
    this.initialState.login.name = value
  }
}
```

And I injected this inside one component.
But when I write something on Input, any input is not being appeard
Could you recommend some solution?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react'

@inject('SignUpIn')
@observer
class SignUp extends Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    const { SignUpIn } = this.props
    SignUpIn.changeLogin(e.target.name, e.target.value)
  }

  render () {
    const { SignUpIn } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={SignUpIn.initialState.login.email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SignUp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this

```
@action changeLogin = (name, value) => {
    this.initialState.login[name]= value
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to remind the reason about `kkangil` solution:-

When you are using (.) notation to access the object property, it will look for string value of the property name.

`this.initialState.login.name` : This will just look for the string value of `name` in the object.

Where as using the bracket notation `[]`, the property identifiers have to be string or a variable that
*references* the string.

So, you can use name which is a variable that is referencing another string.

eg

```
var obj = {
    charmandar: 'fire',
    squirtle: 'water'
}

var charmandar = 'squirtle'
```

> console.log(obj.charmandar);   // fire
>
> console.log(obj[charmandar]);  // water